# as3 stopping sound removes eventListener?

Tags: actionscript-3, audio, event-listener, soundchannel

I am having an issue with stopping a sound and then starting it back up. After I stop the sound and start it again the eventListener seems to be gone.

Now the "easy" fix seems to be just "add" another one when you start the sound again.
This can not be done easily because the sound channel "Praying" has dynamic listener 
added to it with a different function called at the end of each. So I would have to know what listener was added to it and what function should be called when done.

Again, I simply want to "pause" the currently prayed prayer with mouse click and start it up in the same spot with another click. But the issue is that it is removing the eventListener with the  instructions for what to do after the sound is done playing.

Any thoughts on a work around? Or maybe this is an easy fix?

```
 /// EXAMPLE 1
 Praying = OFE.play();
 Praying.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, prayDecade );

 /// EXAMPLE 2
 Praying = JES.play();
 Praying.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, doSomethingElse);

public function togglePraying(e:Event = null)
    {

        if(nowPraying)
        {
            Praying.stop();
            nowPraying = ! Praying;
            trace("Praying: " + currentSound);
        }
        else
        {
            Praying = currentSound.play();
            nowPraying = ! Praying;
            trace("Praying: " + Praying);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You also apparently set `nowPraying` to a wrong value, you should have `nowPraying = !nowPraying`.

Answer (score 2):

This is normal, when you call OFE.play(), you get a SoundChannel reference and if you call it another time, you get a **NEW REFERENCE**. You need to register the event again, but don't forget to remove the listener.

```
if(nowPraying)
{
    Praying.removeEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, doSomethingElse);
    Praying.stop();
    nowPraying = ! Praying;
    trace("Praying: " + currentSound);
}
```